# tensorflow sparse categorical cross entropy with logits

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am a novice programmer trying to follow [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/text_generation) guide.
However, I ran across an issue. The guide says to define the loss function as:

```
def loss(labels, logits):
    return tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(labels, logits, from_logits=True)
```

This gives me the following error:

> sparse_categorical_crossentropy() got an unexpected keyword argument
>   'from_logits'

which I take to mean that `from_logits` is an argument not specified in the function, which is supported by the documentation, which that `tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy()` has only two possible inputs.

Is there a way to specify that logits are being used or is that even necesarry?

Comment: You might want to verify that you have the correct version of tensorflow.

Comment: For reference: [`tf.keras.backend.sparse_categorical_crossentropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/sparse_categorical_crossentropy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `from_logits` parameter is introduced in Tensorflow 1.13.

You can compare 1.12 and 1.13 with these urls:

```
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.13/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py
```

1.13 is not released at the time of writing. This is why the tutorial starts with the line

```
!pip install -q tf-nightly
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem while working through the tutorial.  I changed the code from

```
def loss(labels, logits):
    return tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(labels, logits, from_logits=True)
```

to

```
def loss(labels, logits):
    return tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels, logits=logits)
```

and this resolved the issue without having to install tf-nightly.